# How to color the rows with the same content with one color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with several rows (row number is changeable). It is showing the users details like usernames and IPs and country ....

I want to show the rows with the same IPs with the same colors.

But the content is not static and maybe I have two groups of similar IPs **how can I show each group with one color ?**

I tried to give the name attribute of each TR the value of the IP so all the group with the same IP has the same name attribute.

```
$txt .='<tr name="'.$ip.'"><td>'.$username.'</td><td>'.$ip.'</td><td>'.$country.'</td><td>'.$platform.'</td><td>'.$browser.'</td><td>'.$version.'</td><td>'.$os.'</td><td>'.$lastseen.'</td></tr>';
```

then I use javascript to give a background color for the same name `<tr>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
        ip = $(this).attr('name');
            $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
              ip1 = $(this).attr('name');
                  if(ip == ip1)
                  { $(this).css("background-color","red");}


             });
    });
});
</script>
```

the color of the rows is keep changing and if i have two groups of similar IPs i can not figure out how to separate them into different colors?

Comment: How many different IP addresses are you likely to have, and how does the IP address relate to the colour?

Comment: I want to show similar IPs with the same color to find the users using the same network or the same ip with different accounts . and i have about 2000 users

Comment: Set a CSS class on each TD attribute <td class="ip1">, then you simply use the .ClassName css block to style them accordingly. No need for Jquery here I don't think.

Comment: but i do not know which rows have the same ips to give them the same class???? if i know that my problem will be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ip's itself to color the rows, by treating the blocks as RGB values and assign them as background color for the row.

*e.g*

```
 192.168.0.1
  R   G  B
 background-color: rgb (192,168,0)
```

> I have two groups of similar IPs

Since *similar* isn't specified

I'm using only the first 3 blocks to calcualte the colors since that would group the ips which would be in the same `/24` subnet.

---

Actually assigning those values is pretty straightforward.

```
var table = document.getElementById ("ips");
var rows = table.querySelectorAll ("tr td");
for (var i=0,r=rows;i<r.length;i++) {
    var td = r[i];
    var ip = td.childNodes [0].data.replace (/\s/g,"");   //trim whitespaces
    var rgb = ip.split (".").slice (0,-1);                //get the first 3 blocks (RGB)
    td.style.background = "rgb(" + rgb + ")";             //[].toString () gives a comma seperated values string
}
```

Here is a simple [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLmEJ/1), producing these colors:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oo4c.png]

The resulting colors may not be perceived as beautiful as colors chosen randomly from a predefined set, but it's a simple way to make sure ips, sharing the same blocks get colored the same way.

---

*Edit*

As @MohammedJoraid pointed out, the color distributions for ips, that differ only slightly in the same block, are perceptionally hard to distinguish.

The problem doesn't fade if you change the distribution because we already cover the whole rgb range when even taking only the first three blocks of the address into account.

But we can use an approach that at makes it easier to distinguis such, above mentioned, ips, more easily, by using a HSV colorspace instead of RGB to distribute the colors.

```
var table = document.getElementById("ips");
var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr td");

for (var i = 0, r = rows; i < r.length; i++) {
    var td = r[i],
        ip = td.childNodes[0].data.replace(/\s/g, ""),
        rgb = ip.split(".").slice(0, -1); //get the first three blocks

    var h = rgb.reduce(function (a, b, i) {
        return a + (b * (0.103005665*(1+i*2))) //lastColor + (currentColor * (2*blockNr+1/6*phi)) Practically putting a weight on the blocks further to the right
    }, 0) % 1,
        s = 0.5,
        v = 0.85;

    td.style.background = "rgb(" + hsvToRgb(h, s, v) + ")"; //assign the calculated rgb value
}


function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    var sec = ~~ (h * 6);
    var f = h * 6 - sec;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    var r = 0xFF,
        g = 0xFF,
        b = 0xFF;
    switch (sec) {
        case 0:
            r = v;
            g = t;
            b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            r = q, g = v, b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = p, g = v, b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            r = p, g = q, b = v;
            break;
        case 4:
            r = t, g = p, b = v;
            break;
        case 5:
            r = v, g = p, b = q
    }
    return [~~ (r * 256), ~~ (g * 256), ~~ (b * 256)];
};
```

The new approach colors the table the following way

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyaZb.png]

Heres another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/GLmEJ/2/)

Comment: But they are different ips and still have the same color? what i'm missing here ?

Comment: IP is 4 blocks, not 3, you could join the last last ip part with the 3rd

Comment: @MohammedJoraid Of course they consist of 4 blocks, but do you want to color each host differently? The OP says *"I have two groups of similar IPs"*, the question is what is similar? Ip's in the same network? If we would have a more precise definition of similar or a subnetmask for each ip we could e.g use only the network part of the address to calculate the color, since this isn't given i thought using /24 to group the ip's into similar ones would be fine.

Comment: yes, you are correct we need a better definition of what is similar. 
Besides, your idea is nice, cuz even if you wan to consider the 4th ip group, you can add it to one of RGP so it will produce the same color (for same network group) but with different hue level for end terminals with different subbasement. So people using same router will have somehow the same color :)

Comment: But, let's say you change 192.168.0.2 to 198.168.1.1 it will give you the same exact color, at least for the naked eye. Small Changes in RGP are not easy to notice! and your code also treat one level change in ip to one value change in color which is wrong ( 193.168.178.78 !==  192.168.178.78) but they both show same color

Comment: this ( 192.162.272.52 !==  190.160.270.50) ===>
rgb(190, 160, 255)
rgb(192, 162, 255);
B is not used since we exceeded 255. Maybe i'm a color blind, but both colors look the same to me, 2 RGP increment won't make that difference.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid I get your point, that's indeed true, but there would be no way to distinguish all possible ip combinations by color, as there are more possible values as colors the eye can distinguish. But you're totally right that the color distribution should be changed, such that values in a block differing slightly get more perceptionally different colors. I'll update the Answer

Comment: @MohammedJoraid Updated the answer :) If you have any suggestions for a better distribution of colors, I would be glad to hear it. 
Btw thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this using the following steps:

> 1. Check which IP's are all available
> 2. Create random colors for each IP
> 3. Apply colors to html elements

The code for this would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // First read all available IP addresses
    var ips = [];

    $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
        ip = $(this).attr('name');
        if (ips.indexOf(ip) == -1)
            ips.push(ip);
    });

    // Now create some colors for the ips
    var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
        var color = get_random_color(); // Create some random color here
        colors.push(color);
    }

   // Last step, apply colors to rows
   $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
        var ip = $(this).attr('name');
        var color = colors[ips.indexOf(ip)];
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
   });
});


function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Keeping two parallel arrays might not be a good idea, try keeping a single object, `ipColorObj = {'#AABBCC':'ip1'}`

Comment: @tewathia While this is true, I think my code is easier to understand for newcomers to javascript

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that the randomly generated color is not already assigned to some ip

Comment: @tewathia With 16777216 possibilities I don't think that's gonna happen :P Also its just a code for demo purposes. He can still alter the function "get_random_color" to fit his needs (maybe make sure the colors have some contrast to each other...)

Answer (score 1):

I made this functin as general as possible to suite more scenarios. [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PNSjr/1/)

[image: RESULT]

You can color any table row that has the same value by specifying the class name for the table data. You can search `by class name` and you may add a class to your IP  e.g 
`<td class="_ip">` to make finding ip field easier.

```
var ips = $("._ip"); // get an array of all <td> with _ip class. 
var ip_color = {};//object to save ips with their color
//loop thru all td with the class_ip
$.each(ips, function(index, table_data) {
    var ip = $.trim($(table_data).html());//table_data is the actual <td>
    var color = getColor();
    if (!ip_color[ip])
    {    //use the ip as the object key, therefore we will end up with unique ips. 
        ip_color[ip] = {"color": color, "ref": [table_data]};// add a color and an array of td associated with an ip
    }
    else
    {
        ip_color[ip]["ref"].push(table_data);// we already have the color, we just add the td
    }
});
// here we give each tr a color
$.each(ip_color, function(ip, details) {    //loop thru all unique ips   
    $.each(details.ref, function(index, td) {// loop thru all td
         $(td).closest('tr').css({'background-color': details.color});
    });       
});
function getColor()
{
    return '#' + ('000000' + parseInt(Math.random() * (256 * 256 * 256 - 1)).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find unique ips from trs and then change colors accordingly. js is like

```
var ips = [];

$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
    ip = $(this).attr('name');

    ips.push(ip);
});

ips = jQuery.unique(ips);
var colors = ['red','blue','green'];
var ie = 0;

$.each(ips,function(i,e) {
     if(ie > colors.length-1)
          ie = 0;

     $('table tr[name="' + e + '"]').css('background-color',colors[ie]);
       ie++;

});
```

you can find example in http://jsfiddle.net/DhqQ5/